# UPDATE при определёном условии

Tags: php, sql

Имеется 15 полей для изменения информации. Всё работает в том случае, если заполнены все поля. Подскажите, пожалуйста, условие и запрос, при котором запрос будет работать даже когда заполнено любое количество полей?

**Контроллер:**

```
    public function addConfigurationAction() {
    if (!$this->model->selectAddConfiguration($this->route['id'])) { // Вывод информации в placeholder
        $this->view->errorCode(404);
    } else {
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->model->start($this->model->updateConfiguration($_POST, $this->route['id']))[0]; // Update
        } 
        $vars = [
            'data' => $this->model->selectAddConfiguration($this->route['id'])[0],
        ];
    }
    $this->view->render('ConfigurationPool', $vars);
    
}
```

**Модель:**

```
 public function updateConfiguration($post, $id) {
    $params = [
        'pool_0' => $post['pool_0'],
        'user_0' => $post['user_0'],
        'pass_0' => $post['pass_0'],
        'pool_1' => $post['pool_1'],
        'user_1' => $post['user_1'],
        'pass_1' => $post['pass_1'],
        'pool_2' => $post['pool_2'],
        'user_2' => $post['user_2'],
        'pass_2' => $post['pass_2'],
        'pool_3' => $post['pool_3'],
        'user_3' => $post['user_3'],
        'pass_3' => $post['pass_3'],
        'pool_4' => $post['pool_4'],
        'user_4' => $post['user_4'],
        'pass_4' => $post['pass_4'],
        'id' => $id,
    ];
    $this->db->query('UPDATE config SET
    pool_0 = :pool_0, user_1 = :user_0, pass_0 = :pass_0, pool_1 = :pool_1, user_1 = :user_1,
    pass_1 = :pass_1, pool_2 = :pool_2, user_2 = :pass_2, pass_2 = :pass_2, pool_3 = :pool_3,
    user_3 = :user_3, pass_3 = :pass_3, pool_4 = :pool_4, user_4 = :user_4, pass_4 = :pass_4
    WHERE id_0 = :id', $params);
}
```

**Форма:**

```
        <form method="POST" class="form_general">
        <input type="text" name="pool_0" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pool_0']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="user_0" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['user_0']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pass_0" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pass_0']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pool_1" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pool_1']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="user_1" class="general" style="margin-top:30px;" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pool_1']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pass_1" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pass_1']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pool_2" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pool_2']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="user_2" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['user_2']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pass_2" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pass_2']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pool_3" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pool_3']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="user_3" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['user_3']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pass_3" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pass_3']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pool_4" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pool_4']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="user_4" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['user_4']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="pass_4" class="general" placeholder="<?php echo $data['pass_4']; ?>"><br>
        <?php


      ?>
        <input type="submit" class="save" value="Save" name="save">
    </form>

введите сюда код
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET column = COALESCE(:new_value, column)` - при условии, что при отсутствии значения в запрос подставляется NULL. Если нет - то зависит от того, что именно попадает в запрос.

Comment: @Akina, Благодарю, а если нужно что бы, в поле в котором было значение не менялось на NULL, а оставалось без изменения, если оно не было задействовано?

Comment: Тогда наоборот - `UPDATE ... SET column = COALESCE(column, :new_value)`. Значение будет установлено только для записи, где в этом поле NULL.

Comment: а почему вы текущие значения не пишите в value у input ?